# Building a filter for 'any of these dates' against a DateTime field in MongoDB collection

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a method that will retrieve documents from collections that have a datetime stamp field named `Date`.  The method is passed a list of datetimes (with `00:00:00` time).

Suppose the list has 3 datetimes.
I am trying to figure out how to construct a filter to retrieve documents with

```
// pseudo-code
.Type != "Header" &
.Type != "" &
( ( datetime[0] <= .Date & .Date < datetime[0].AddDays(1) ) |
  ( datetime[1] <= .Date & .Date < datetime[1].AddDays(1) ) |
  ( datetime[2] <= .Date & .Date < datetime[2].AddDays(1) )
)
```

or perhaps

```
.Type != "Header" &
.Type != "" &
.Date(DatePartOf) in (datetime[0], datetime[1], datetime[2])
```

What I have

```
private Task LoadCollection(string collectionName, List<ListItem_Date> dates)
{
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
            var filter = 
                  builder.Ne("Type", "Header") 
                & builder.Ne("Type", (string)null)
                & 
//
// Not sure what can go here to filter to the list of dates 
//
            ;

            var collectionDocuments =
                Database
                .GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName)
                .Find(filter)
                .ToList()
            ;

            …
```

Comment: Did you tried `var filter = builder.Ne("Type", "Header") & builder.Ne("Type", (string)null) & builder.In("Date",  dates);`

Comment: Will be trying that, but potential problem with `.In("Date", dates)` is the time portion. The date values in the documents are like `2018-01-01T05:02:38.000+00:00` and the date values in the list are like `2018-01-01T00:00:00+00:00`

Comment: You may try to access Today property on date("Date.Today") then. I can't find anything in docs, but may be worth trying.  `var filter = builder.Ne("Type", "Header") & builder.Ne("Type", (string)null) & builder.In("Date.Today", dates);`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a working filter with the following code:

```
    private Task LoadCollection(string collectionName, List<DateTime> dates) 
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
            var dateRangeFilters = new List<FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>>();
            foreach (DateTime item in dates)
            {
                dateRangeFilters.Add(
                    builder.Gte("Date", item.Date) 
                    &
                    builder.Lt("Date", item.Date.AddDays(1)));
            }

            var anyOfTheseDatesFilter = builder.Or(dateRangeFilters);

            var filter = 
                  builder.Ne("Type", "Header") 
                & builder.Ne("Type", (string)null)
                & anyOfTheseDatesFilter
            ;

            var collectionDocuments =
                Database
                .GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName)
                .Find(filter)
                .ToList()
            ;
```